# How much food does one livestock give?

Tags: banished

I've been buying food for my 1k+ citizen city but seems not enough, dropping from 100k food to 50k 
I've planed to buy livestock and kill it rightaway for food, my first impression is:
Cattle gives 200 food, (i don't know how much leather) u can sell this for 3 each, and buy vegetables, means u get 600 for doing it. looks like is not worth it, but i don't know with sheeps and chickens, any help?.

My question is different, because im not willing to make fences to farm livestock, I want to kill livestock as soon as i get em. The question is: Is it worth it? considering ships only trading animals are a "waste" in the sense i can't buy food from them, making food gathering slower.

Answer (score 3):

### TLDR: Instead of spending your exports on livestock to process at a loss and resell the meat for produce, just buy the the produce with your exports in the 1st place.

If a Trader comes to you with nothing you need, there is nothing wrong with telling him to pack up & move along.  The sooner you end your business with a trader the sooner the next one will be along.

In the end, (surplus) Meat, Firewood, simple Coats, and (non-wheat) Ale are great (renewable) exports.  Seeds & Livestock are poor imports for any town that already has that particular species.

---

According to banishedinfo.com: Slaughtering a cow gets you 6 leather & 200 beef, slaughtering a sheep gets you 200 Mutton, and slaughtering a chicken (animal) gets you 6 chicken (food).  Making the purchase of Cattle & Chickens for slaughter a "bad trade" & Sheep an investment of labor for no value gained.

- Cattle @ 800 -> 200 Beef @ 3 + 6 Leather @ 10 = 660 or a **loss of 140**.
- Sheep @ 600 -> 200 Mutton @ 3 = 600 or breaking even if you don't count the time invested for the herdsman to slaughter, laborers to store & traders to return to the post.
- Chickens @ 400 -> 6 chicken @ 3 = 18 or a **loss of 382**.

Eggs & Wool are byproducts of keeping a number of your chickens & sheep alive.

---

## Why are we doing this?

### A) If you want to process *imports* for profit:

- Logs -> Firewood
- Fruit -> Ale
- Leather *or* Wool -> Coats

Warm Coats are great for keeping your people working but worth less in trade.  Make Hide/Wool Coats for trade.

Tools can be made from imports at a small profit, but as Iron & Coal are not renewable, there may be more value in stockpiling Steel Tools.

### B) If you want a source of protein for your people:

If you want to import your protein, buy nuts or fish.

There are 4 sources of home grown protein in the game:

- Fishing Dock: The Fishing Dock is labor intensive, but has a very small footprint and utilizes otherwise hard to use real-estate.
- Hunting Cabin: The Hunting Cabin is likewise labor intensive and requires a large land reservation, but in an early town may be your only source of clothing materials.
- Orchard (growing nuts): Orchards, like Crop Fields, are land and labor efficient, but require a few years before they become productive and are subject to the vagaries of weather.
- Pasture: Pastures are likewise land and labor efficient, can provide raw materials for your Tailor, but have a considerable startup time.  Chickens have a great growth rate, reducing startup time, but produce the least protein and nothing for the Tailor.  Cattle in a pasture can be a replacement for your Hunting Lodge.  Sheep are king!  They supply the most protein for your pasture and wool equal to 3 times the leather produced by the same sized cattle pasture.  Prepare to export Wool Coats!

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a bug. Sometimes people are just short-sided and will pay more for one thing without considering the alternatives. (That is, unless the mechanics of the game are designed to prevent this.) I wouldn't have any "moral issue" with taking advantage of this, unless it's ridiculously off balance. Just my two cents.

Comment: Well I havn't time on my pc but for the numbers i have IT IS WORTH IT, ull get meat for almost x units of trade in which 2<x<3. I hav'n't thought about it but it is in fact, in the strict mean of exploit, a real exploit but not an overpowered... Someone did mention fruits -> ale, I hadn't thought of that! thx a lot.